# Why does using \DOTSM in macro definitions cause an error?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I currently have the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\dotprod}{\DOTSM\cdot}

\begin{document}

$a\dotprod b$

\end{document}
```

but when I try to compile it, I get the error `Undefined control sequence.` On the other hand, if I replace `\DOTSM` with `\DOTSB`, I don't get an error. I find this strange since both `\dotsb` and `\dotsm` are valid commands. What is going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `\DOTSM` is not defined.

Comment: You can use `\DOTSB`, `\DOTSI` or `\DOTSX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amsmath defines

```
\let\dotsb\cdots
\let\dotsm\cdots
```

so these are aliases for the same thing, but the internal forms do not need or have aliases and so there is no `\DOTSM`

Comment: I was just thinking, `amsmath` creates the different commands, `\dotsb` and `\dotsm`, so that they can be independently redefined to match different conventions on the fly. However, even if `\dotsb` and `\dotsm` have been redefined so that they no longer match, there's still no need to have a `\DOTSM` command since it looks better to just write `a\dotsm b`, as opposed to `a\dotprod\dots\dotprod b`.